# String return from member function in C++

Tags: c++, compilation

I am a c programmer and have just started using c++. In c if we return address from function the address which we are passing will not be valid until and unless we have dynamically allocated that memory.
But here in C++ i did't allocated a memory to store the string.
Is that address of string "a" will be valid even after returning from function copy_string.
Why in main function it is returning correct string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class String_copy{
public:
        string str1;
        string str2;
        string copy_string(string str);
  };

  string String_copy::copy_string(string str)
  {
          string a;
          string b;

          b="Hello World!";

          a = str+" "+b;
          return a;
  }

  int main(void)
  {
    String_copy str;
    str.str1="Wooo";
    str.str2 = str.copy_string(str.str1);
    cout << "Final string is \"" << str.str2 << "\"" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: A `string` is not a `char *`.

Comment: You need to review your `C` knowledge.  `C` has the same behavior as what you're seeing in the code here.  Imagine `string` being a struct in C, what happens when you return the struct by value?

Comment: See this C example here: http://ideone.com/VJ1sH4   You will see that the struct is copied, no different than the string object being copied.  The difference is that C++ allows you to "fine tune" how the copy is made by making this function available (via copy constructor and assignment op).

Comment: Thanks Paul for explaining it. I was assuming that string was treated as char * in c++ but it is just a value not a pointer. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C and C++ as opposed to C# and Java, variables do not need to be allocated in dynamic memory, which includes strings and character arrays.

If you *need* or *want* to return pointers from a function, they must point to some variable that won't disappear after execution leaves the function.  The two popular techniques are to use `static` variables or variables allocated from dynamic memory.  Both `static` and dynamically allocated variables will be around after the execution leaves the function.

You may be confusing `std::string` with C style character arrays.  The `std::string` class is an object and can be return from a function like an integer or double.

Technically, a C-Style string can be returned from a function without using pointers.  Much like returning an array of integers.

Common practice in C is to return pointers to an array to refrain from copying large data structures.  So the convention is to return a pointer to C-Style string and the target must be either `static` or dynamically allocated, so the target of the pointer doesn't disappear after execution leaves the function.